# Python: Return rows where the same IDs are within 30 days of the next

Tags: python, pandas

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,3,4,4],'ID2':[1,1,1,1,2,1]\
                  ,'dts1':['2016-1-25','2016-1-25','2016-1-25','2016-2-20','2016-1-25','2016-2-20']
                 ,'dts2':['2016-1-27','2016-1-27','2016-1-27','2016-2-24','2016-1-27','2016-2-24']})
```

I have a data frame like:

```
        ID  ID2   dts1         dts2
    0   1   1   2016-1-25   2016-1-27
    1   2   1   2016-1-25   2016-1-27
    2   3   1   2016-1-25   2016-1-27
    3   3   1   2016-2-20   2016-2-24
    4   4   2   2016-1-25   2016-1-27
    5   4   1   2016-2-20   2016-2-24
```

I want rows that are 1) have the same ID 2) have different ID2 3) have a dts2 within 30 days of the next dts1 of the next row with the same ID...

For this dataframe I would want the last two rows (where ID = next ID, ID2 != next ID2 and dts2 < next dts1 + 30 days

****EDIT***

```
    ts_df[ts_df.groupby(['ID']).apply(lambda x: ((x['dts1'].shift(-1)-x['dts2']<=pd.Timedelta('30days'))\
                                        &(x['ID2'].shift(-1)!=x['ID2']))|\
                                        ((x['dts1']-x['dts2'].shift(1)<=pd.Timedelta('30days'))\
                                        &(x['ID2']!=x['ID2'].shift(1)))).values]
```

The only think I have found to work is the above ^

It is super slow (22 min on my dataset), so any improvement would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```py
test['dts1'] = pd.to_datetime(test['dts1'])
test['dts2'] = pd.to_datetime(test['dts2'])

def get_what_you_need(df):
    mask1 = df[df.duplicated(subset='ID', keep=False)]
    mask2 = mask1.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID', 'ID2'], keep=False).reset_index(drop=True)
    idx = 0
    if len(df) >= 2:        
        mask3 = (mask2.loc[idx + 1, 'dts1'] - mask2.loc[idx, 'dts2']) < pd.Timedelta(days = 30)
    else:
        return None

    if mask3:
        return mask2
    else:
        return None

get_what_you_need(test)
```

I put `idx` and `days` as constants here. If you want, you could set the `idx` and `days` as the parameters of the function.

Comment: Wouldn't this only return two rows if the first time the ID was unique and the ID2 didn't match had that delta?